# spring-boot, Jetty setup results in authenticated failed for username Already authenticated as UNAUTHENTICATED

Tags: spring-boot, security, authentication, jetty, openam

i am doing migration from jboss to jetty and during login it fails see stacktrace bellow at the end.

I am using a OncePerRequestFilter where I am invoking request.login(requestEksternSsoToken, null);

and then it says I am already authenticated as UNAUTHENTICATED. What is the problem and how can I fix it ?

```
14:05:05.602 [qtp1288135425-15] DEBUG n.n.m.s.filter.OpenAMLoginFilter - Login failed.
org.eclipse.jetty.server.Authentication$Failed: Authenticated failed for username 'AQIC5wjhfjsdhfjksdhfjadshfjdhssjdfhasdkhf'. Already authenticated as UNAUTHENTICATED
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.login(Request.java:2530)
        at xx.xxxx.xxxx.security.filter.OpenAMLoginFilter.login(OpenAMLoginFilter.java:165)
        at xx.xxx.xxxx.security.filter.OpenAMLoginFilter.handleNoExistingLogin(OpenAMLoginFilter.java:95)
        at xx.xxxxx.xxxxx.security.filter.OpenAMLoginFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenAMLoginFilter.java:71)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:548)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:602)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:235)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1624)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1435)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:501)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1594)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1350)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:516)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:388)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:633)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:380)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:277)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:882)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1036)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

UPDATE:

Here I have written a configuration of Jetty where I am configuring security constraint still it is throwing the same error in my filter when I attempt to invoke login.

```
@Configuration
public class JettyConfig {
    private static final Logger logger = getLogger(JettyConfig.class);

    
    @Bean
    WebServerFactoryCustomizer embeddedServletContainerCustomizer(final JettyServerCustomizer jettyServerCustomizer) {
    
        return container -> {
            if (container instanceof JettyServletWebServerFactory) {
                logger.info("Adding jetty server customizer");
                ((JettyServletWebServerFactory) container).addServerCustomizers(jettyServerCustomizer);
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    JettyServerCustomizer jettyServerCustomizer(final LoginService loginService,ConstraintSecurityHandler constraintSecurityHandler) {
        return server -> {
            logger.info("Setting loginService");
            ((WebAppContext) server.getHandler()).setSecurityHandler(constraintSecurityHandler);
        };// .setSecurityHandler(constraintSecurityHandler);
    }

    @Bean
    ConstraintSecurityHandler constraintSecurityHandler(final LoginService loginService) {
        final ConstraintSecurityHandler securityHandler = new ConstraintSecurityHandler();

        securityHandler.setLoginService(loginService);
        
       Constraint constraint = new Constraint();
       constraint.setName("Auth");
       ConstraintMapping mapping = new ConstraintMapping();
       mapping.setPathSpec("/*");
       mapping.setConstraint(constraint);
       securityHandler.addConstraintMapping(mapping);
       securityHandler.setLoginService(loginService);
      

        return securityHandler;
    }
   
    
    @Bean
    LoginService loginService()  {
        JAASLoginService jaas = new JAASLoginService("OpenAM Realm");
        jaas.setLoginModuleName("openam");
        return jaas;
    }
```

Comment: This means your `Request.getAuthentication()` wasn't setup properly, which is setup by your `SecurityHandler.getAuthenticator()`, which appears to have not been setup. (do you have security constraints setup in your descriptor?)

Comment: No I have not. I will try it tomorrow. Thanks!

Comment: Hei @JoakimErdfelt can you have a look at the posted code. I did configure the security constraints. I remind you that get the token from OpenAM and I use the filter in order to invoke login with the already obtained token. What am I missing here ? I ahve also set System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config", loginConfFile);

Comment: If this is still an issue, can you please file an issue at https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues

Comment: As long as the jaas config is external to the Jar of the spring boot application it is working. Same setup using embeded jetty is working without spring boot when the conf is included in the jar. I guess something is different with resource lossing in spring boot But i can’t say what.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the problem on my own. It apears that in contrast to Embeded Jetty deployment the webapp/web-inf directory is not exmploded and then spring boot is not able to find the jaas login.conf file and it is failing to load the login module silently. Setting explicitly the configuration from a location resolves the issue:

```
JAASLoginService jaas = new JAASLoginService("OpenAM Realm");
        jaas.setLoginModuleName("openam");
        final String loginConfFile = "/app/login.conf";//Applcation.class.getClassLoader().getResource("login.conf").getFile();
        logger.info("login.conf file location is " + loginConfFile);
        File file = (new File(loginConfFile));
        logger.info("uri is " + file.toURI());
        ConfigFile configfile = new ConfigFile(file.toURI());
        jaas.setConfiguration(configfile);
```